# Проблема с установкой Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, manjaro

я хочу перейти с Windows 10 на Manjaro Linux, но не получается, появляются какие-то ошибки.
Загрузочный носитель я делал с помощью Rufus`a и [ISO образа](https://manjaro.org/download/)(Official Editions->Plasma Desktop->Download->Torrent&Full), биос у меня - UEFI BIOS Utility

Вот что появляется при загрузке с флешки (остальные диски я отключил, потому что с ними у меня просто загружается Windows)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираю proprietary drivers и выводится такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения], также я пробовал с open source drivers, ошибка точно-такая же

В интернете ничего годного не нашёл

Comment: в rufus  по идее нужно выбрать режим dd при записи, еще как вариант попробуйте записать с помощью [win32diskimager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

Comment: да можно, но не с этим iso файлом, когда я его загружаю, он блокирует все параметры, незнаю как с другими, но с образом arch linux такого нету

Comment: @Zt. А где взять IMG образ manjaro ?

Comment: win32diskimager тоже не работает ?
еще можете создать мультизагрузочную флешку с помощью [Ventoy](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy) и затем просто в подготовленный раздел скинуть iso образ

Comment: @Zt. само приложение работает, я не понимаю где взять файл с разрешением .img/.IMG

Comment: img на скока я вижу на офсайте есть тока для arm-платформы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась.
Просто поменял флешку на другую, видимо со старой были какие-то проблемы, для превращения флешки в загрузочную, я использовал тот же образ и тот же Rufus

Answer (score 0):

надо перекачать образ и проверить контрольные суммы, были такие ошибки при кривом образе, для записи можно юзать [ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/), после создания через него загрузочного носителя на этот носитель можно накидать разные образы и выявлять в чем проблем, в образе, носителе или железе, можно освоить [virtualbox](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) и в нем попрактиковаться прежде чем на живое железо ставить